# How to compare a previous list and updated a field in multi thread

Tags: multithreading, list, kotlin, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I have a local cache where I store the runner's lap info, I need to show if the runner's current lap was better or worse than the current lap, while displaying the current lap information.

```
data class RunInfo(
    val runnerId: String,
    val lapTime: Double,
    var betterThanLastLap: BETTERTHANLASTLAP
)

enum class BETTERTHANLASTLAP {
    NA, YES, NO
}

object RunDB {

    private var listOfRunners: MutableList<RunInfo> =
        java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(mutableListOf())
    private var previousList: MutableList<RunInfo> = mutableListOf()

    fun save(runList: MutableList<RunInfo>) {
        previousList = listOfRunners.toMutableList()
        listOfRunners.clear()
        listOfRunners.addAll(runList)
        listOfRunners.forEach { runner ->
            previousList.forEach { previousLap ->
                if (runner.runnerId == previousLap.runnerId) {
                    runner.betterThanLastLap =
                        when {
                            previousLap.lapTime == 0.0 -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NA
                            runner.lapTime >= previousLap.lapTime -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.YES
                            else -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NO
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to do the job, but often I get concurrent modification exception. Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Well, I don't see any concurrent code here. How is `RubDB.save` executed? One more remark: make sure that `listOfRunners.toMutableList()` is actually making a copy of your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend combining mutable lists with read-write `var` properties. Making it mutable in two different ways creates ambiguity and is error prone. Since you're just clearing and replacing the list contents, I would make it a read-only list and a read-write property.

You need to synchronize the whole function so it can only be executed once at a time.

```
object RunDB {

    private var listOfRunners: List<RunInfo> = listOf()
    private var previousList: List<RunInfo> = listOf()

    fun save(runList: List<RunInfo>) {
        sychronized(this) {
            previousList = listOfRunners.toList()
            listOfRunners = runList.toList()
            listOfRunners.forEach { runner ->
                previousList.forEach { previousLap ->
                    if (runner.runnerId == previousLap.runnerId) {
                        runner.betterThanLastLap =
                            when {
                                previousLap.lapTime == 0.0 -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NA
                                runner.lapTime >= previousLap.lapTime -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.YES
                                else -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NO
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It also feels error prone to have a mutable data class in these lists that you're copying and shuffling around. I recommend making it immutable:

```
data class RunInfo(
    val runnerId: String,
    val lapTime: Double,
    val betterThanLastLap: BETTERTHANLASTLAP
)

object RunDB {

    private var listOfRunners: List<RunInfo> = listOf()
    private var previousList: List<RunInfo> = listOf()

    fun save(runList: List<RunInfo>) {
        sychronized(this) {
            previousList = listOfRunners.toList()
            listOfRunners = runList.map { runner ->
                val previousLap = previousList.find { runner.runnerId == previousLap.runnerId }
                runner.copy(betterThanLastLap = when {
                    previousLap == null || previousLap.lapTime == 0.0 -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NA
                    runner.lapTime >= previousLap.lapTime -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.YES
                    else -> BETTERTHANLASTLAP.NO
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All great advice.  Especially for defaulting to immutability except where there's a reason to be mutable.  Also worth highlighting that _all_ access to those lists must be `synchronized`, so take care if you add any other functions using them, and do _not_ let anything outside the object get hold of them.  (That's the problem with synchronisation: it's all-or-nothing, and easy to get wrong — and most bugs won't appear until you're running in production under heavy load…)  So life will be easier if you add comments explaining that, and if `RunDB` does nothing else and remains small.